# Selenium Java By CSS Selectors dealing with multiple languages

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a script that runs many websites in various languages. How can I include all languages in one BY selector. Usually, I would use an ID to keep it tiny, but the item is missing an ID. When I run an assert it picks up all the items.

For example my By Selector looks like this :

```
By.cssSelector("zerv-item > [aria-label='ENGLISH'],
    zerv-item > [aria-label='FRENCH'],
    zerv-item > [aria-label='SPANISH'],
    zerv-item > [aria-label='ARAB']"
);
```

I could just break the object into multiple parts like englishObject, spanishObject, etc.
However, would be nice not to have redundancy like that.